# When should smpp return ESME_RALYBND and ESME_RINVBNDSTS?

Tags: smpp

When should smsc return ESME_RALYBND ("ESME Already in Bound State") as per smpp? Specification doesn't say about what to return when ESME is already in bound state. But looking at error description if another bind received it must be returned with ESME_RALYBND

Also

When should "ESME_RINVBNDSTS" ("Incorrect BIND Status for given command") be returned? is "bind_transceiver -> unbind -> submit_sm" should returned this error?

Answer (score 3):

Nasir,
As per my knowledge, ESME_RALYBND can be used typically in below case
ESME already has an active binding with the given SMSC and over the same binding, another Bind request is sent. Something like

```
bind_transmitter/bind_transciever >>
bind_response <<
bind_tranmitter/bind_transciever >>
ESME_RALYBND <<
```

For ESME_RINVBNDSTS
this example should explain it crearly

```
bind_receiver >>
bind_receiver_response <<
submit_sm >>
ESME_RINVBNDSTS <<
```

If you try to perform an operation which is not supported by type of binding like in case of receiver type of binding you can not submit_sm.
I hope this answers yours doubts.

Comment: Where is this explained in standard? Because some smpp implementation just return success for second bind_transmitter.

Comment: SMPP has very less documentation around this and the standard ways. That is why different providers have different implementations.